# Adding 2 large numbers using stack?

Tags: c, stack

I'm currently learning C programming language (it's my very first programming language too). I'm now dealing with the problem that adding 2 large numbers using stack. I've written some codes to solve it but I'm facing some errors.

Here is my code.

## Main program

```
#include "stack.h"
#include <string.h>

int main(){
  node *top1,*top2,*top3;
  int i=0,n1,n2,flag=0,adder;
  char number1[50],number2[50];
  printf("Enter the first number: ");
  scanf(" %s",number1);
  printf("Enter the second number: ");
  scanf(" %s",number2);
  n1 = strlen(number1);
  n2 = strlen(number2);

  while (i<=n1 || i<=n2){
    push(top1,(number1[i]-'0'));
    push(top2,(number2[i]-'0'));
    i++;
  }

  while(!isEmpty(top1) || !isEmpty(top2)){
    adder = pop(top1) + pop(top2) + flag;
    if (adder >= 10) {
      push(top3,adder-10);
      flag = 1;
    } else {
      push(top3,adder);
      flag=0;
    }
  }
  printf("The result is: ");
  while (!isEmpty(top3)){
    printf("%d",pop(top3));
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

## stack.h lib

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int ElementType;
typedef struct node_t {
  ElementType data;
  struct node_t *next;
}node;

int isEmpty(node *top){
  return (top==NULL);
}

void push(node *top,ElementType value){
  node *p;
  p = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
  if (p==NULL) {
    printf("Allocation failed!\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  p->data = value;
  p->next=top;
  top = p;
}

ElementType pop(node *top){
  if (isEmpty(top)){
    printf("The stack is empty!\n");
    return 0;
  } else {
  node *p;
  ElementType value;
  value = top->data;
  p = top;
  top = top->next;
  free(p);
  return value;
  }
}
```

It's done compiling but when I input 2 numbers then a Core Dump error appears. I tried to use gdb to find out and here is the result.

```
#0  0x00007ffff7a44267 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:55
#1  0x00007ffff7a45eca in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00007ffff7a87c53 in __libc_message (do_abort=do_abort@entry=1, 
    fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff7ba01a8 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n")
    at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
#3  0x00007ffff7a939f8 in malloc_printerr (ptr=<optimized out>, 
    str=0x7ffff7ba01d0 "munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer", 
    action=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:4965
#4  munmap_chunk (p=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:2820
#5  __GI___libc_free (mem=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:2945
#6  0x000000000040083c in push (top=0x7fffffffe201, value=1) at stack.h:24
#7  0x0000000000400955 in main () at teststack1.c:16
(gdb)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the errors you're trying to solve please?  If the code doesn't compile, include a note of the compiler errors.  If the code runs but produces surprising output, note the input and expected/actual output.

Comment: @simonc thank you ! I've updated. I hope you can help me, I searched all the question but no one has the same error with me.
If you need something more, just command me. I need to improve :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The segmentation fault is probably caused by the fact you are freeing your `top` in the `push` function. You really don't want to do that, because the calling code is working with it. But there are some other flaws in the program. For example: 
The logic in the code is wrong:

```
while(!isEmpty(top1) || !isEmpty(top2)){
    adder = pop(top1) + pop(top2) + flag;
.....
```

The condition will be true while **either** `top1` or `top2` are non-empty. It means that one of them *can* be empty. But then you are trying to `pop` from both of them, even the empty one.

Comment: Thank you! I thought if the stack is empty then the function `pop` will `return 0`, am I right or not ? so to be more precise, I edited my code to   `return 0` in `if` condition.
Also in `push` function, p is just a temporary node, so when I put `p=top` then I can `free(p)`. can I ?

Comment: Right now there is an empty "return" statement in there, which is not correct as well. And it should print that the stack is empty.

Comment: @balabolo `p` has the same value as `top`, so being a pointer, referencing the same memory location. So making free on `p` is the same as making `free` on `top` - it is releasing that memory location.

Comment: I've edited my code but now it turns to having error at freeing p in pop function. I bet that p (which has the same address with previous top) should be freed, right?

Comment: There is another problem in `pop`. You are actually modifying the *value* of the `top` pointer by `top=top->next`. But since it is passed by value to the function, the calling code won't "see" that change. If you want to continue with the same function signatures, you should overwrite the *contents* of `top` rather than `top` itself (like `top->value=top->next>value; top->next = top->next->next`. With appropriate checks, of course.

Comment: Thank you for your enthusiasm. Finally, I can tackle my problem using your advice and also my friends. I should use `node **top` in 2 `pop` and `push` function. Exactly, I want to modify the value of `top` pointer but if i passed the `top` pointer to function then the code won't "see" that change (as you mention).   
(for those who don't know and have the same prob with me)
PEACE ! :D